# Increased Execution TIme even with increased number of CPUs, Why?

Tags: c++, architecture, operating-system, cluster-computing, hpc

I have run the same C++ problem size of different number of CPUs on an HPC cluster, but what I figured out is that when the number of CPUs increased the execution time also increased. I was expecting a significant decrease in execution time. Can anyone shed some light in this issue?

Below are my execution times per # of CPUs

```
  Number of CPUs      Problem size         Time (seconds)
  1                   3000000              15.48
  2                   3000000              18.2
  4                   3000000              21.73
  8                   3000000              40.55
  16                  3000000              60.14
  32                  3000000              98.75
```

My thoughts:

- Too much communications increased between the CPUs that leads to increased the execution time.

Comment: Maybe this can help? [How too many vCPUs can negatively affect performance](http://www.gabesvirtualworld.com/how-too-many-vcpus-can-negatively-affect-your-performance/). Also take a look at this: [Scalability with Fixed Problem Size](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node30.html)

Comment: Is your C++ code parallelised? How do you submit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this explains it:

"There are two major factors that influence performance: the speed of the CPUs themselves, and the **speed of** their **access to memor**y. In a cluster, it’s fairly obvious that a given CPU will have fastest access to the RAM within the same computer (node). Perhaps more surprisingly, similar issues are relevant on a typical multicore laptop, due to differences in the speed of main memory and the cache. Consequently, a good multiprocessing environment should allow control over the “ownership” of a chunk of memory by a particular CPU."